# Filtering out items using SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml

Been looking around and am stumped. Basically I'm trying to filter out a result from an xml feed and hide it from displaying in the html output. I'm trying to find out the venue  "Hornblower Cruises and Events" and if it exists, hide the whole , which is the parent of all the nodes.

Here's the URL: http://www.sandiegomagazine.com/goldstartest/rss3-exclude.php

Here's my code:

```
<?php
 $myfeed = simplexml_load_file('https://www.goldstar.com/api/listings.xml?api_key=6d0d598c69dfecfcf028b0d2b3c9b693b606ad8c&postal_code=92101');
 $i = 0;
foreach ($myfeed as $goldstar): 
    $title=$goldstar->headline_as_html; 
    $summary=$goldstar->summary_as_html; 
    $dates=$goldstar->upcoming_dates->event_date->date; 
    $ourprice=$goldstar->our_price_range; 
    $fullprice=$goldstar->full_price_range; 
    $img=$goldstar->image; 
    $link=$goldstar->link; 
    $venue_name=$goldstar->venue->name;
    $venue_street=$goldstar->venue->address->street_address;
    $venue_locality=$goldstar->venue->address->locality;
    $venue_region=$goldstar->venue->address->region;
    $venue_zip=$goldstar->venue->address->postal_code;
    $venue_phone=$goldstar->venue->phone;
    $category=$goldstar->category_list->category->name;


   // if ($venue_name == 'Hornblower Cruises and Events'){
     // unset($myfeed->event);
        //echo $myfeed->asxml();

    //}

    if (++$i > 20) {
    // stop after 10 loops
    break;
}


?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>







<div class="gs-item">
<div class="gs-itemcontent">

<h3 class="gs-cat"><?php echo $category; ?></h3>
<h2><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $title; ?></a></h2>
<h4 class="gs-date">Date: <?php echo $dates; ?> <br/>For more show dates, <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank">click here</a></h4>

<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" />
<p><?php echo $summary; ?></p>


<div id="gs-callout">
<span class="fullprice">Full Price: <?php echo $fullprice; ?></span>
<br/>
<span class="ourprice">Our Price:  <span class="gs-hilite"><?php echo $ourprice; ?></span></span>
 <p><a class="gs-button" href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_blank">Buy Tickets &raquo;</a></p>

</div>


<ul class="gs-venue">
<li><strong><?php echo $venue_name; ?></strong> | </li>
<li><?php echo $venue_street; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $venue_locality; ?>, <?php echo $venue_region; ?> <?php echo $venue_zip; ?></li>
<li><?php echo $venue_phone; ?></li>


</ul> 

</div>
<div class="gs-clear"></div>
</div>







    <?  endforeach; ?>



</body>
```

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a keyed foreach

```
 foreach ($myfeed as $key => $goldstar):
```

And then unset the entire current xml using the key

```
unset($myfeed->$key);
```

Or unset just the venue with unset($myfeed->$key->venue);

Alternately, you could just build a new obj instead of trying to edit the existing one. Instantiate a new object before your loop and then only add the pieces to it that you want to keep.

Or, you can just continue the foreach if you find the unwanted venue.  The only downside is that you won't have a copy of your ok'd list in $myfeed.  So...

```
if ($venue_name == 'Hornblower Cruises and Events') { continue; }
```

Comment: Not working :( I'm still not doing something right.


Thanks @M_user

I wrote the follow ing, but it returns the item I want to delete, as part of a list of 7 items (loops asks for 20). Is the following closer?


        
        
`if ($venue_name == ('Hornblower Cruises and Events')){`
`unset($myfeed->$key);`
` }`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should cast every object that you are getting from your SimpleXML object to the relevant type. For example you should cast string attributes or nodes with putting `(string)` before reading the field:

```
$venue_name = (string)$goldstar->venue->name
```

For your question about filtering, I'd suggest your own way to keep looking for the match string and then decide to add or not.

**EDIT**

You're trying to see if the venue name is `'Hornblower Cruises and Events'` then unset the current event field and echo it as XML? Firstly you should write `unset($myfeed)` because it's the event field itself. Next `asxml` would return nothing if you unset `$myfeed`. And you have `HTML` mistake in your code. In every loop of your `for`, you're writing:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
```

You should place them before the `for`. And there is no closing tag for them. Put the closing tags after `for`. If you want to just get the fields with not venue name `'Hornblower Cruises and Events'`, put the `<?php if($venue_name != 'Hornblower Cruises and Events') : ?>` before `<div class="gs-item">` and put `<?php endif; ?>` after `</ul>`.

Comment: Thank you @MahanGM, I'm a bit of a noob, so would this work?

I casted all the items, then i wrote:


    `if ($venue_name == ('Hornblower Cruises and Events')){`
         `unset($myfeed->event);`
   `echo $myfeed->asxml();`
        
       `}`

Comment: it seems to be returning 7 items, rather than the 20 i set the loop to, and still showing the <event> i want to hide

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you @MahanGM, it worked! I didn't even have to use `unset();` 

Thank you for pointing out the `<html>` error as well. I missed that being so focused on the filter.